# how to add Blog portlet in websphere portal?

Tags: websphere-portal

How to add blogging feature into websphere portal application? Webspeher sever version is 5.0. and portlet application version is 5.1.

Guide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I know that Portal version 7 comes with a Blog portlet but I'm not sure about Portal 5. If it does then you should be able to easily add that portlet to any page. If it doesn't then you'll need to get a portlet that implements the features you want.

This task in general should be very basic so I would first recommend reading the documentation for Portal. This link is probably most relevant to your immediate question, but I do suggest getting more familiar with the platform by reading more sections of the Infocenter.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wpdoc/v510/topic/com.ibm.wp.ent.doc/wps/adctinsp.html

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the Portlet catalog available [here](https://greenhouse.lotus.com/catalog/)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very old and outdated version of WebSphere Portal, so my first suggestion would be to upgrade to version 7 or (preferably) 8. By doing so you will be able to make use of the new Blog feature backed by WCM in the portal.

But, upgrading is not always an option. Considering that I would say that your best bet would be to either write your own portlet based blog system, or to use an existing blog system (there are plentiful of Open Source variants) and link them into the portal using a simple IFRAME portlet.

Comment: Could you please give me some sample good opensource application to include into portlet? That application should support LDAp authentication support? I don't find anything exactly.

Comment: I have planned to go with wordpress.org. will it work with IFrame portlet.

Comment: Wordpress will probably work ok, given that you select (or build) a theme that looks ok integrated within the portal UI. 

You will probably want to try to get single sign on so that the user does not have to log in both in the portal and Wordpress, you can use the credential vault service for storing the WP credentials and use them to automatically log in the user: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wpdoc/v510/topic/com.ibm.wp.ent.doc_5.1/wpf/sec_vault.html